# Azure devops build pipeline with yaml file not working

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I have created a build-pipeline.yml file for my project, so that my application can be built automatically in azure devops.

fistly I have created a pipeline with devops UI, that works very well.

so I have copyed all yml from jobs, which I have created with UI.

and then I have created a new Pipeline with this yml file and run this pipeline, but I got some problems at the beginning:

```
##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError
,##[error]Provisioning request delayed or failed to send 3 time(s). This is over the limit of 3 time(s).

Pool: Azure Pipelines
Started: Today at 10:07
Duration: <1s

Job preparation parameters
1 queue time variable used
system.debug : false


Report build status
<1s
Set build status for commit e720d4.
```

my yaml file looks just like this:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'build image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'TOOL'
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"abc.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/a03e9b30-9b04-4e89-b366-117b3d6bf17e/resourceGroups/abcrg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/abcacr"}'

- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'push image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'RCTOOL'
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"abctoolacr.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/a03e9b30-9b04-4ed5-b3898-117b3d6bf17e/resourceGroups/abc-acr-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/abctoolacr"}'
    action: 'Push an image'

- task: HelmInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Helm '

- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'Package Helm chart'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'RCTOOL'
    azureResourceGroup: 'abc-rctool-k8s-rg'
    kubernetesCluster: 'abc-rctool-k8s'
    command: package
    chartPath: config/helm/eqcockpit

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
```

so I have googled, but I have not found any useful solutions. may be you can help me.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? What about use vmImage in your YAML? Does the below answer can help you escape the error?

Comment: Hi there, did the solution below fix your issue? If so, please mark as answer. If not, let us know any new information to help further

Answer (score 12):

It just looks like your `pool` needs updating. Choose from this list: [Hosted Agent Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent)
Example

```
pool:
  vmImage: vs2017-win2016
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Worked for me :)

Comment: this didn't work for me. I use a parameter to select the pool, like this:

```
pool:
  name: {{ parameters['myPool'] }}
```

With self hosted agent it's no problem.

But it fails with "Azure pipelines"

Comment: You'll have to specify the actual pool name, such as "vs2017-win2016". "Azure Pipelines" won't work.

Comment: it works for me, thanks